# How to achieve this COUNT(date > NOW()) AS count?

Tags: mysql, date, count

I have a table with a list of live tour dates, and I would like to GROUP them per year, but also create a new column with remaining dates for this year :

```
  year   |  count /*of remaining dates*/
  --------------------
  2014   |  12
  2013   |  0
  2012   |  0
  2010   |  0
```

I tried this but is doesn't work :

```
SELECT YEAR(`date`) AS year, COUNT(`date` > NOW()) AS count
FROM live
GROUP BY YEAR(`date`) 
ORDER BY YEAR(`date`) DESC
```

Comment: use `SUM()` instead of `COUNT()`. `date > NOW()` will return 1 or 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it this way

```
SELECT YEAR(`date`) AS year, SUM(`date` > CURDATE()) AS count
  FROM live
GROUP BY YEAR(`date`) DESC
```

Sample output:

```
| YEAR | COUNT |
|------|-------|
| 2013 |     2 |
| 2012 |     0 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b438fc/3)** demo